# change date format when using python and tkcalendar

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

When using tkcalendar with python , how do you change the format of your get_date result ? 
For instance , I am getting , YYYY-MM-DD. I want to the result to be ISO format like this : YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Below is my code :

```
def showdate():
    messagebox.showinfo("your date is ", ent.get_date())
    print(ent.get_date())
mylabeldate=Label(header_frame,text="select an experation date ")
mylabeldate.grid(row=2,column=0)
ent=DateEntry(header_frame)
ent.grid(row=3,column=0)
mybuton=Button(header_frame,text="click me ",command=showdate)
mybuton.grid(row=4,column=0)
```

Comment: What do you expect the `HH:MM:SS` to be?

Comment: 00:00:00 would be okay

Comment: Then do `messagebox.showinfo("your date is ", f"{ent.get_date()} 00:00:00")`.